# Component / Broker template publishing error with SI4T / DD4T

Tags: publishing, dd4t, deployer, si4t

We are in the process of upgrading from SDL Tridion 2011 HR1 to SDL Web 8.1.1. We are well within the support matrix in terms of OS (Windows 2008 R2 SP1) and SQL (SQL 2012 SP).

We have completed the following:

1. Upgrade is complete in CM and Deployer databases.
2. We have the CMS site up and wired with a java deployer (`Deployer Service.war`).
3. We are now encountering an issue when we publish our broker template or Components integrated with SI4T.
4. Our SOLR version is 4.2 and the error we get are two fold.
5. When we publish a component presentation to SOLR we get an **"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.tridion.storage.ComponentPresentation.getContent()Ljava/lang/String;"** error.
6. When we publish the broker template we get a transport error. The transport error are returning without a cause. We have increased the content length in the `web.config` file under `webui/webroot/web.config` file.
7. The size of the package is around 84 MB. The error we get is **"ERROR BaseHTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to send TransportPackage to url: http://165.88.41.146:8080/deployer-service/httpupload cause: "** in the transport log without any cause.

I'd appreciate if you could provide some directions for us.

- We have DD4T and SI4T integrations to our site. DD4T pages are deploying properly while the SI4T are not.
- We have installed the legacy pack.

Comment: In CME, the default allowed size is 30MB, you need to increase  that in Tridion service host config as well, your package creation does use tridion core service before transport.

Comment: For Si4t search - Did you add your Generate Index Field TBB to your Default Finish Action TBB..? Pls provide full stacktrace?